# SimpleAdapter notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to refresh my ListView whenever I delete an item on it. But setting a `notifyDataSetChanged();` is giving me this error:

Cannot refer to a non-final variable adapter inside an inner class
   defined in a different method.

The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type
   ListAdapter.

```
ArrayList <HashMap <String, String> > data = dataHolder.getAllData();
dataHolder.getAllData();

if(data.size() !=0){

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.datalist);
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, data, R.layout.dataentry, new String[]{"unique_id","lastName"}, new int[]{R.id.unique_id,R.id.last_name});
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    adb.setTitle("Delete?");
                    adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                    adb.setMessage("Delete selected item?");
                    adb.setCancelable(false);
                    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                    adb.setPositiveButton("Delete", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        TextView uID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.unique_id);
                        String unique_id = uID.getText().toString();
                        dataHolder.deleteData(unique_id);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });  
                adb.show();
                return false;
                }
            });
}
```

Then it suggests to change it to:

```
((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, data, R.layout.dataentry, new String[]{"unique_id","lastName"}, new int[]{R.id.unique_id,R.id.last_name});
```

But it's not refreshing the list after changing to that. What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. Must remove first the item from the array list of the listview before notifying data set changed.

```
data.remove(position);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 3):

To reference `adapter` from within the `AlertDialog.OnClickListener`, [you need it to be final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class) (that's basically what the error tells you). So just declare it `final`:

```
final BaseAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, data, R.layout.dataentry, new String[]{"unique_id","lastName"}, new int[]{R.id.unique_id,R.id.last_name});
```

You could also just grab it from the parameters you are called with:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // ...
    final Adapter adapter = adapterView.getAdapter();
    if (adapter instanceof BaseAdapter) {
        ((BaseAdapter)adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected adapter");
    }
```

for example.

Answer (score 1):

Make your adapter a field of the class instead of a local variable. 
Also, dont declare it using the ListAdapter interface, but a real class with the method that you need to use, so you dont need to cast, for instance

```
 BaseAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(....
```

and also...please note that the data colection of your adapter, is in `data`, and you are deleting the item from `dataHolder`, that i dont know what is. please check that actually `data` is being changed when `dataHolder` changes, otherwise the list wont change.

I think that is the problem. when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` it will check if data has changed. And probably it has not, and the adapter doesn't know how to get it again from `dataHolder`. Thats why it is not working. you should pass a variable that is changed inside the dataHolder, or create your own adatper that receives the `dataholder` as data, and call `getAllData()` to retrieve the update when `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called.

Other easier approach is that you create a `public ArrayList <HashMap <String, String> > data` in your `dataHolder`. That `data` is modified when you call `deleteData` or when you insert data to the `dataHodler`. And that `dataHolder.data` is what you pass to the adapter in the constructor:

```
new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, dataHolder.data, R.layout.dataentry, new String[]{"unique_id","lastName"}, new int[]{R.id.unique_id,R.id.last_name});
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggest and add BaseAdapter adapter; as global variable. But it still doesn't refresh my ListView. It refreshes only when I exit the activity and open it again.

Comment: what is dataHolder and how is it related to data?

Comment: "dataHolder" is a class where I create table in sqlite and insert my gathered data inside and the "data" is a method inside my dataHolder

Comment: and what is the data variable that you pass to the adapter constructor? you get it from data holder calling data()?

Comment: i think that is the problem. when you call notifyDataSetChanged() it will check if data has changed. and probably it wont, and the adapter doesnt know how to get it again from dataHolder. thats why it is not working. you should pass a variable that is changed inside the dataHolder, or create your own adatper that receives the dataholder has data.

Comment: i guess it is what i say in the last comment. data array is not being changed. The best would be to create your own adapter, but that wont be  the easier. The easier is that you create a `ArrayList <HashMap <String, String> > data` in your dataHolder. that data is modified when  you call `deleteData` or when you insert data to the dataHodler. and that dataHolder.data is what you pass to the adapter in the constructor: `new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, dataHolder.data, R.layout.dataentry, new String[]{"unique_id","lastName"}, new int[]{R.id.unique_id,R.id.last_name});`

Comment: check at my update, and please try it, im pretty sure it will work.

Comment: I'll try it later. I discovered another problem (the first item is the one that always being deleted) and I'm currently trying to solve it.

Comment: ok, if you want, write another question and give me the link. Also dont forget to try to solve this problem so you can see if my answer works and upvote or accept or whatever so it is finally useful to other users, and also i get some value :)

Comment: I found the solution sir. data.remove(position) before the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score -1):

just declare your ListAdapter as global variable

Comment: you are trying to access a local adapter inside an inner class that is the reason it is telling you to make it final.... so remove the ListAdapter from the local scope and declare it as global